# Capture the original value of an Angular model for in-place editing

Tags: angularjs

I built a simple in-place editing solution for profile data in my app.  The problem is, if someone edits a field and modify the text of that field but choose "cancel," instead of save, because of Angular's bindings, the text change is still displayed in the UI.

I was thinking that when someone it "edit profile," I would capture the original value of the field so that if they hit cancel, it could restore the original text.

```
  $scope.editProfile = ->
    $scope.editState = true
    $scope.originalDescription = $scope.user.profile.description
```

Of course, something like this doesn't work.  I do want to capture $scope.user.profile.description at the time that editProfile function is called.

Any suggestions for strategies here?

Comment: What problem are you facing on resetting the original description? Have a cancel function in controller with the statement: $scope.user.profile.description = $scope.originialDescription

Comment: This seems to work.  I had tried that before I had thought and the $scope.originaldescription was still binding to any changes made to $scope.user.profile.description.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is:

```
angular.copy($scope.user.profile.description, $scope.description.backup)
```

and if you need to restore the original values:

```
angular.copy($scope.description.backup, $scope.user.profile.description)
```